# Texas hold'em: Why did I lose this hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, reading-hands, wsop

I was playing Texas hold'em in WSoP 2008: Battle for the Bracelets. It came down to me and one other player, and I lost but I don't know why.

Her hand:
T♥J♥

My hand:
J♠J♣

Flop:
T♠Q♦K♣A♠A♦

It looks to me like we both had straights of 10, J, Q, K, and A, while I had a J leftover and she had a 10 leftover. My J should've beaten her 10, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: You might have been thinking of Omaha where you *have* to use both your hole cards. In this case you would have lost since her straight would have beaten your two pair.

Comment: @Robbie Dee you'd have *four* hole cards in Omaha...

Comment: But you MUST use 2 - which isn't necessarily true in hold em

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold'em Poker means having the 5 best cards available, your hand + board, and her hand + board.
You both made a straight, doesn't matter what u have left over.

This setup is a split pot, i guess u mixed something up. She probably had 10 and Ace or Ace Queen or Ace King  for a  Full House, which beats a straight.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your quick response. You're right. I made a mistake (sorry, I'm an idiot). It turns out that we actually tied, but the game only showed the victory animation for her and not me, so I thought that she beat me. Thanks again.

Comment: you are not an idiot. you are learning and keep the stuff in your head ;) please accept my answer since i love points *ggg*